# What is the correct approach to upgrade Docker when a gpg file is involved?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, docker

After to did do an upgrade through VirtualBox for Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 to 22.04 - `focal` to `jammy` - at the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory exists the `mysql.list` file.

According with a research was indicated to open that file and change from `local` to `jammy`. Therefore I have now

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0
manueljordan@mac2013-vb143:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

Now at the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory exists the `docker.list` and `docker.list.distUpgrade` files as follows

```
cat docker.list
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   focal stable

cat docker.list.distUpgrade 
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   focal stable
```

Yes the `/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg` file exists

What is the correct approach to upgrade Docker when a gpg file is involved?

Answer (score 1):

During a release upgrade, To adjust your third party repository, you sometimes need to change the release codename. But you don't need to change the gpg key.

If a gpg key has been changed, `apt` will warn you. You have to override the old key. e,g: (docker gpg key)

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

[Dealing with third party APT repositories in Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/third-party-apt-repositories)

Comment: Thanks, let me test it soon as I can